# Count items with certain state even if the amount is zero in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have a two tables - items and its states. Each item has only one state. I need to get list of states with counted items of that state, but only from certain ower. When I remove `WHERE` part I get list of all states, but with it I get only some of states, because there are not at all same states used in items with owner `no.7`. How to get all of states even if it's amount is zero?

Only solution I have is use subquery instead of `COUNT(i.id)`, but that would be much more slower and I am afraid of performance.

**My tables:**

```
ID   STATE NAME
==   ==========
1    New
2    Used
3    Archived
4    Unknown

ID   STATE   ITEM NAME   OWNER
==   =====   =========   =====
1    1       ABC         7
2    2       DEF         6
3    3       GHI         7
4    1       JKL         7
```

**My query:**

```
SELECT
 s.id,
 s.name,
 COUNT(i.id) AS count
FROM
 b_items_states s
LEFT JOIN
 b_items i ON i.state = s.id
WHERE
 i.owner = 7
GROUP BY
 s.id
```

**My result:**

```
ID   NAME      COUNT
==   ====      =====
1    New       2
3    Archived  1
```

**My expected result:**

```
ID   NAME      COUNT
==   ====      =====
1    New       2
2    Used      0
3    Archived  1
4    Unknown   0
```

Comment: Move  `i.owner = 7` to the `ON` clause to get true `LEFT JOIN` result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the filtering condition inside the JOIN, as in:

```
SELECT
 s.id,
 s.name,
 COUNT(i.id) AS count
FROM
 b_items_states s
LEFT JOIN
 b_items i ON i.state = s.id AND i.owner = 7
GROUP BY
 s.id
```

If you place the filtering condition in a `WHERE` statement, you are implicitly converting the outer join into an inner join, without even noticing.

Comment: Perfect, that's it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Impaler has a correct answer

You can also express this as a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT s.id, s.name,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM b_items i
        WHERE i.state = s.id AND
              i.owner = 7
       ) as count
FROM b_items_states s;
```

In particular, this can take advantage of an index on `b_items(state, owner)`.  By avoiding the outer aggregation, it should have better performance.